# EAR generated using ANT doesn't work on Websphere 8.5

Tags: deployment, ant, websphere, wsadmin

The object is to build .ear by using ANT then deploy it on Websphere 8.5 with wsadmin.

Manually, the ear file is generated from a jar file and after deployment, the web application works very well.

But if I use the ear generated by ANT, after deployment (by hand or by wsadmin), I always have this error :

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /WebApp$%7Blogout.url%7D has not been defined.
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:9080 has not been defined.
```

Someone knows which might invoke this problem. I met this message before while my colleague deploy on websphere with a war file directly from a Tomcat server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not defined web application bindings during deployment. There are several ways to do this, but before that I suggest that you read about [Application bindings](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/crun_app_bindings.html) in WAS, especially the paragraph **Virtual host bindings for web modules**.

Required bindings can be provided either as parameters to `install` command of [AdminApp](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html) or by including binding files directly inside WAR. In some cases WAS can generate default binding for you. For example, to install web application with default bindings you need to provide the following command to `wsadmin` (simplified):

```
AdminApp.install(path_to_your_war_file, [
'-appname', your_app_name,
'-CtxRootForWebMod', [
    ['.*', '.*', your_app_context_root]
],
'-usedefaultbindings'])
```

I also recommend deploying application once in WAS console to understand possible bindings.

Comment: Hi fnt, thanks for your answer. In my situation, the context root is defined in application.xml in ear file. The problem might exists during the generation of ear file by ANT. Because if I use wsadmin commands to deploy a ear file generated by manual installation, all works fine

Comment: During manual installation binding are generated and placed into the deployment. You should compare EAR created by Ant and the one after deployment. You will see binding files that were added.